# How to save documents with CAS aware policy in Aerospike Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, aerospike

Could anyone show me how we could save documents with CAS aware policy in **Spring Data Aerospike** so that it uses the generation from the record to update the document with **EXPECT_GEN_EQUAL** generation policy?

I tried this:

```
Customer customer = customerRepositoryTest.findOne("335672888");
customer.setFieldX(some value)
customerRepository.save(customer);
```

But I found out the Aerospike Spring Data always use the NONE Generation Policy so that it always ignores the version property (generation) and overwrites the record when calling `save`.

Anyone got an idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `spring-data-aerospike` dependency with `groupId` com.aerospike as it contains all contributed fixes to the project:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aerospike/spring-data-aerospike

`2.2.0.RELEASE` is already supporting Spring Boot 2.2.
`2.1.1.RELEASE` is for Spring Boot 2.1.